# How can I do Google Sitemap for Spring boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mvcsitemapprovider, xml-sitemap

I have a spring application deployed on the cloud server, digital ocean.

i tried to generate the sitemap.xml file using https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ but it only gives me one page. which can be access on https://hostname.com

i would like my sitemap to have something like

1. https://hostname.com/page1
2. https://hostname.com/page2

how can i make a sitemap for other pages which are bundle in a war file in a spring boot application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at exporting URLs mentioned in controllers, then you can get the URLs list from `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerMapping re;

    @GetMapping("/sitemap.xml")
    public String getSitemap() {
        Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethods = re.getHandlerMethods();
        List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Entry<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> entry : handlerMethods.entrySet()) {
            urls.addAll((entry.getKey().getPatternsCondition().getPatterns()));
        }
        // Construct XML response from urls and return it
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I get dynamic sitemap, I have API @RequestMapping(value="/sitemap / {state}") where state is dynamic. I am getting response- <url>
  <loc>https://examplexyz.com/sitemap/{state}</loc>
</url>
I want something like this, <url>
  <loc>https://examplexyz.com/sitemap/California</loc>
  <lastmod>2019-02-25T10:28:08+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.64</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://examplexyz.com/sitemap/Hawaii</loc>
  <lastmod>2019-02-25T10:28:08+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.64</priority>
</url>